# Why does my table look OK in the back-end but is not formatted correctly in the font-end?

Tags: articles

The following table is displaying correctly in the back-end. Why is it not displayed correctly in the front-end?

```
<table border="1" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; text-align: center; width: 833px; height: 204px;" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
                <tbody style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0;">
                    <tr style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0;">
                        <td rowspan="2" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0;"><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; color: #000080;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-size: medium;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-family: Arial;">&nbsp; REGULAR&nbsp; <br /></span></span></span></strong>
                        </td>
                        <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0;">&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td colspan="3" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; text-align: center;"><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; color: #000080;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-size: medium;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-family: Arial;">&nbsp; ASSOCIATE &nbsp;&nbsp; <br /></span></span></span></strong>
                        </td>
                        <td rowspan="2" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0;"><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; color: #000080;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-size: medium;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-family: Arial;">&nbsp;&nbsp; MOTORSPORTS&nbsp;&nbsp; <br /></span></span></span></strong>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0;">
                        <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; color: #000080;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-size: medium;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-family: Arial;">&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Individual &nbsp;&nbsp;</span></span> </span>
                        </td>
                        <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; text-align: center;">&nbsp; &nbsp;<span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-family: Arial;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-size: medium;">&nbsp; <span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; color: #000080;">PIDP&nbsp; &nbsp; </span></span>
                            </span><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-family: Arial;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-size: medium;"><br /></span></span></strong>
                        </td>
                        <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; color: #000080;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-size: medium;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-family: Arial;">Individual</span></span> </span>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; color: #000080;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-size: medium;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-family: Arial;">Group</span></span> </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0;">
                        <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-size: small;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-family: Arial;">ERS interventions per year</span></span>
                        </td>
                        <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-size: small;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-family: Arial;">4 interventions or 100 km tow distance whichever comes first</span></span>
                        </td>
                        <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-size: small;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-family: Arial;">4 interventions or 100 km tow distance whichever comes first</span></span>
                        </td>
                        <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-size: small;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-family: Arial;">3 interventions or 60 km tow distance whichever comes first</span></span>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-family: Arial;">2 interventions or 40 km tow distance whichever comes first</span></span>
                        </td>
                        <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; text-align: center;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-size: small;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-family: Arial;">4 interventions or 100 km tow distance whichever comes first</span></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: At the back end it is OK/fixed and I tried to create a new table in article it is still the same. At the back it is good and fixed, but in front/live it is disarrange. Thank you for the response.

Comment: **Hint:** You may want to do some research on `colspan` which you're using on your `td` elements.

Comment: Have edited to emphasise the Joomla part of the question which is being drowned out by ugly in-line table styling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely cause that your table looks different in the front-end is table styling in your `template.css` file or similar.

As it is, much of the existing styling code is duplicated and hard to read and you would be better moving as much of the styling information as possible into CSS.

Ideally, custom CSS should be placed in a `custom.css` file or similar (assuming your template has this feature) or you could add a custom CSS file using a third party extension like [CSSConfig](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/templating/24523) or similar.

For example you could simplify your table cell HTML from this:

```
<td style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; text-align: center;">
  <span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-size: small;">
    <span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; font-family: Arial;">
      4 interventions or 100 km tow distance whichever comes first
    </span>
  </span>
</td>
```

to this:

```
<td>
  4 interventions or 100 km tow distance whichever comes first
</td>
```

by creating some CSS like this:

```
td {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: small;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

Once simplified as per the above example, it will likely be easier to see why the table looks different in the front-end and be able to fix it easily in CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that creating constant layouts with tables isn't that easy or flexible and also can easily break. Especially when you are using too much inline-css and try to fill in cell's space with non-breaking spaces. Also regarding any differences you see in the front-end, consider that your table most likely is affected by css that is loaded with your template.

The best approach would be to have a totally plain table, containing only the data, give this table a special class or id, and then target and style it with css from an external css file e.g. custom.css of your template.